# http service hit not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular5

I am using JSONPlaceholder to get data in service, but I am unable to get data at all. Please, help me out.

**user.component.html**

```
<p (click)="getUsers()">Click Me!</p>
<ul *ngFor="let x of users">
  <li>{{x.name}}, {{x.age}}</li>
</ul>
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getUsers(){
    console.log(this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
  }  

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
//Basic File Inclusions
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

//Additional files inclusion
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [ Http ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please, can someone help me out making a successfull service call via http and get data on console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

in app.module.ts

```
imports: [HttpModule]
```

Rest of code will be same as you posted.

calling http like

```
this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data)
        }); 

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
//Basic File Inclusions
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

//Additional files inclusion
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [ Http ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score -1):

You are just calling `http.get(url)` and expecting something in return is like calling ajax method without success and error callback methods.

Kindly check [Http documentation and usage of get and post methods](https://angular.io/guide/http)

**Mistake/Wrong Assumptions:**

`this.http.get(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)` will not return http response which are expecting

**Reality/Correct Approach:**

You can use either `pipe(can be used in the service)` or `subscribe(can be used in Component)` method on http's get method whose return type is Observable.

Based on your requirement, you can use either of them

```
http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      // Call map on the response observable to get the parsed people object
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
      // Subscribe to the observable to get the parsed people object and attach it to the
      // component
      .subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts)
```

Hence your component code becomes:

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getUsers(){
    this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
     .subscribe(posts=> console.log(posts))
  }  

}
```